# Dymo SDK Javascript and Laravel Print barcode with data from project

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

So i have a Laravel project where data from controller go's to the view like `$product->name` for example

Thats working fine.
Next to that I've Dymo connected service what also works fine when i want to print that product name.

Now I want to print that name on an label through Dymo SDK,But every time I make a barcode and put it into that textarea it shows html markup.

What can I do to change this `label.setObjectText("Address", textTextArea.value);` into a field that cant read `DNS1D::getBarcodeSVG` or `DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML` ?

Because if I throw this into a div `{!! DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML('4445645656', 'C128'); !!}` I see a barcode.